# Weird "No such file" error with "xargs" and "file"

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I'd like to get the MIME type of all files under the current directory. Why doesn't this work? I've tested bash on OSX or Linux. "file" complains that it can't find the file, but if I run it with the exact same path it works.

```
$ find . -type f | xargs -n 1 -I FILE echo $(file --mime-type -b FILE)
ERROR: cannot open './foo.txt' (No such file or directory)
...
$ file --mime-type -b ./foo.txt
text/plain
```

Of course in the real world I don't just "echo" the response, I need to use the MIME type string in another command.

This is the simplest I could make the problem. I guess I'm not understanding something about `xargs` filename substitution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command substitution `$(file --mime-type -b FILE)` is executed by the shell before being passed to `xargs`, which is why you are not seeing what you need. Quote `$(file --mime-type -b FILE)` and pass it to `bash -c` via xargs

```
find . -type f | xargs -n 1 -I FILE bash -c  'echo $(file --mime-type -b FILE)'
```

Comment: ... so making a file named '`FILE`' will demonstrate that nicely.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to make use of `xargs` here. Simply make use of `find`'s `-exec` switch.

```
$ find . -type f -exec file --mime-type -- {} +
```

#### Examples

*default `file` output*

```
$ find 8* -type f -exec file --mime-type -- {} + | tail -5
89999/sample10.txt:               text/plain
89999/sample2.txt:                text/plain
89999/sample4.txt:                text/plain
89999/sample6.txt:                text/plain
89999/sample9.txt:                text/plain
```

*`file -b` output*

```
$ find 8* -type f -exec file --mime-type -b -- {} + | head -5
application/x-empty
text/x-perl
text/plain
text/plain
text/plain
```

#### Alternatives

This is just an FYI, but there is another command called `mimetype` which you can also use to do the same thing as `file --mimetype`. This command is part of this package on Fedora, `perl-File-MimeInfo`, and works similarly:

```
$ find 8* -type f -exec mimetype -- {} + | tail -5
89999/sample10.txt:               text/plain
89999/sample2.txt:                text/plain
89999/sample4.txt:                text/plain
89999/sample6.txt:                text/plain
89999/sample9.txt:                text/plain
```

#### More elaborate exec

Given you inquired about "doing more than just echo.." and since you're attempting to use `xargs` I'm going to conclude that you're thinking you'll need to do more elaborateness with `xargs`.

But if you're using `find`, this is generally not the best way to go. You can instead use `find`, and then within `find`'s `-exec` switch call a shell and do more complicated things within here, rather than try to coax `xargs` into doing this in a more complex way.

```
$ find . -type f -exec sh -c '
   cmd1;
   cmd2;
   file --mime-type -b "$@";
   cmd3;
   cmd4;
 ' sh {} \;
```

**NOTE:** That I've switched from using the `+` terminator which passes multiple arguments to `file --mime-type ...` to `\;` which passes one at a time.

#### Example

```
$ find 8* -type f -exec sh -c '
   echo -n "mime-type: "; 
   file --mime-type -b "$@"
  ' sh {} \; |& tail -10
mime-type: text/plain
mime-type: text/plain
mime-type: text/plain
mime-type: text/plain
mime-type: text/x-shellscript
mime-type: text/plain
mime-type: text/plain
mime-type: text/plain
mime-type: text/plain
mime-type: text/plain
```

Comment: If you don't wrap it, it will undergo shell globbing. Whether that's what you want or not is subjective -- I think what you actually want is `find . -name '8*'`, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @ChrisDown - yeah in my sample data directory I actually did want `8*` 8-). But that's just b/c of my setup.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is about shell expansion. $() is expanded before it is handed over as an argument. If you want to treat it as-is, single quote it and call a shell for it.

Also, if you process filenames, get in the habit of using print0 and 0 as leaving them out will produce problems for you with filenames containing space character.

Example:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I FILE bash -c 'echo $(file --mime-type -b FILE)'
```

In your case this can be simplified to:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 file --mime-type -b
```

An additional comment: Calling a program for all files found (be it 'xargs -n 1' or find+exec) can be a real performance bottleneck. If you have a directory with thousands of files, you will spawn thousands of processes.

Comment: There is a -P option to set max processes in xargs.

Comment: It will still generate a lot of processes, just limits the concurrent number of them. The point is to avoid, whenever possible, a "generate a lot of items -> call a process for each", instead do "generate a lot of items -> call a process that can handle a lot of items". Very basic example to show you the point: Don't call grep for each pattern individually, as a single grep can read a pattern file.